# DictReader should error on wrong column count

Tags: python, csv

Should [`Dialect.strict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.strict) on a `DictReader` make it raise an exception if the number of columns in a line doesn't match the number of header columns?

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) (emphasis mine):

> To make it easier to specify the format of input and output records, specific formatting parameters are grouped together into dialects. A dialect is a subclass of the Dialect class having a set of specific methods and a single validate() method. When creating reader or writer objects, the programmer can specify a string or a subclass of the Dialect class as the dialect parameter. **In addition to**, or instead of, the dialect parameter, the programmer can **also specify individual formatting parameters, which have the same names as the attributes defined below** for the Dialect class.

> Dialect.strict
> When True, raise exception Error on bad CSV input. The default is False.

I interpret that as saying I can set `strict=True` on a `DictReader` and have it raise an `Error` if the number of fields in any line doesn't match the number of fields in the header row.

My code: `test.py`

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('mal.csv')
with path.open(newline="") as f:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, strict=True)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

My csv: `mal.csv`

```
This,Has,many,columns,of,text
This,misses,some
This,has,the,right,number,here
And,here,there,are,too,many,columns,sure,
```

`python ./test.py` doesn't raise an error and prints out the lines correctly. How can I make it error?

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's nothing wrong with your `mal.csv`.

Comment: I guess it all depends on what "on invalid input" means.

Comment: Yeah, I can't find any official description of what "strict" entails, [skimming at the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Modules/_csv.c) I can only find anything related to quoting and unexpected ends of input... This may be worth bringing up as a documentation bug on the official bug tracker, because I don't think it's *intended* to catch the situation you are desire, but I can understand why you might expect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment, I guess `strict` doesn't do what I expected, and I altered my code to manually raise an error if there are any missing values by checking for `None` in `.values()` (since an empty item like `,,` or `,\r\n` is encoded as the empty string):

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('mal.csv')
with path.open(newline="") as f:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, strict=True)
    for line in csv_reader:
        if None in line.values() or None in line.keys():
            raise csv.Error(f"Missing or extra values on line {line}")
        print(line)
```

I also tried changing `DictReader.restval` to be a function or lambda that `raise`s an exception, but this didn't work the way I wanted.

Comment: Since you aren't specifying a *`fieldnames`* argument when you create the `DictReader`, it will treat the first row of the file as containing them. After creation, you can see what (and how many) of them their are by referencing the attribute [`csv_reader.fieldnames`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.fieldnames). This would provide you with a relatively simple way to programmatically check the length of each the remaining rows as they're read (and handle it as you wish).

Comment: @martineau, that is not sufficient to determine if a line is missing values, since those keys will still be present in the dictionary of that line, but with a value of `None`.